# Is it possible to level grind in Normal Mode?

Tags: fire-emblem-three-houses

So in Awakening, we can use Reeking Boxes... but what of Three Houses? I'm not far off from the beginning of the game- I have just recently finished the mock battle, actually, but I noticed this calendar mechanic in the game (and in extension, the activity points stuffs). Apparently, the days just... jump.

With this info, I assume there's only a limited number of days before reaching the so-called War Phase... so this brings me back to the question: are there maps or battles that I can replay again and again so that I can level grind the characters, or are there only a limited amount of maps/battles that I can participate in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you're through the first few weeks, you'll start getting an option for which action to take every Saturday. Your options will be:

- Explore Monastery
- Hold Seminar
- Battle
- Rest.

Battle will allow you to battle bandits. You'll have a limited number of "Battle Points" to use depending on your professor level. You can use these to fight battles related to quests you've picked up in the Monastery, fight the default bandit battle every week or once you're far enough, participate in

> paralogues.

In addition, in Normal Mode, there is always a free battle. Though the enemies will be a couple levels lower than the "paid" battles, you are free to replay these as many times as you'd like with no cost.

Note however, that to learn a new Class/have support conversations/etc., you'll need to be at the Monastery. So you won't be able to do any of these in between battles (until you end the Saturday and go back).

For more on reasons *not* to simply do this every time, see [Is there a reason not to battle every time?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/355312/222207)

Comment: Wait, I’m playing on Normal/classic mode right now but I don’t see these “free battles” on the menu, everything has to be “paid”.

Comment: @Malky.Kid if you're in normal mode, you should see something [like this](https://gamespot1.cbsistatic.com/uploads/scale_super/172/1720905/3564330-paralogues.jpg) (though maybe without the paralogues if you're not that far). The "Battle in the Desert" in that screenshot is the free battle.

Comment: @Malky.Kid The in-game Guide mentions free battles in Normal mode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz9ON.jpg (whoever would like to use this screenshot in their answer is free to do so; no need to upload it to stackexchange, as it has already been uploaded there)

Answer (score 2):

Although I am not that much further than you are, I am quite certain in saying that there are only limited options of gaining levels.

Every Sunday is your day off. You can usually explore the Monastery to do side activities. Some Sundays offer a battle option. What you can do on these days, is either go battle (thus grind levels), or explore the Monastery as usual, effectively skipping that opportunity to battle.

So, even though grinding opportunities are limited, keep in mind that most gains will come from actually lecturing your students in class. That's where they'll get their new arts, classes and skill levels.

In my own experience, it hasn't really been necessary to grind extra levels. At least, on normal. I can't speak for Hard (yet).

Answer (score 2):

On normal there will be free battles later.

Most battles will cost time but a few will be free that you can do over and over again.

Though i heard that's not the case on classic.

> Source: am further into the game where i have seen it myself.

Answer (score 0):

When you retreat from battle, you can start the battle again and keep all XP. If you want to grind levels, fight until you have one enemy left and retreat.

At the same time, you can also manipulate RNG to get better skill gains on leveling. If a level only gives 2 or 3 skills, you can rewind to before level up and then retreat. When you restart the battle, a new set of level up stats are rolled for all characters.

Comment: That's cool! I never knew when you retreat you keep the XP, do you lose anything for retreating, like weapon durability? or is it just more time to have to go and play the map again?

Comment: I just found out about this as well! There's a discussion about this at https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/204445-fire-emblem-three-houses/77890793. Apparently, there aren't any downsides to this. It's only possible to do this on Normal mode, though.

Answer (score 0):

On normal mode, as mentioned by others, it **is** possible to grind levels, you just need to be aware of a few things when hammering out those levels.

You are correct that there is a limited number of days before the "so-called War Phase", you have about 12 months depending on your choices in game, but each day off (once a week) you get to choose if you want to battle or do other things, you almost always have the choice so there is no certain days you *have* to grind.
Of course there are more optimal days to grind, such as days with Rare battles, but you'll see those well in advance when you start each new month and can plan how you will play the month out.

When selecting to do Battle on your day off, you are given a set amount of Battle Points, dependent on your Professor Level.
You will be presented with a large map and on the right is a list of all available battles for that day.
On normal mode only, there is one selection that will not use up any Battle Points, *this option is the only one to not have a big red sword icon on it*.
This battle is repeatable, seemingly as many times as you want, I myself tested it just 3 times.

The other options are not "grindable" as they will consume a Battle Point each when selected.
Once you run out of Battle Points, your day off ends, and you will continue advancing through the calendar.

This will allow you to grind for level if that is what you need, however to advance to better classes and gain more stats you will need your students to complete exams, which they can only do on the "Day Off Menu", at the start of each of your days off.